# What is the best way to create a class structure from a bill of materials?

Tags: java, deserialization

For a semester project (in Java) I have to do some material flow optimization. The starting point for the whole task will be a bill of materials. The user should be able to provide it via a file (xml or yaml). My question is now, how can I build class objects (with dependencies) from this bill of materials automatically?

So far I found a serialization/deserialization framework called simple (http://simple.sourceforge.net/) but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go.

I'm glad for any advice.

Comment: Please be more specific. This is an opinion based question.

Comment: In which way should I be more specific? Could you elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

> The user should be able to provide it via a file (xml or yaml).

First you must know what the structure of the above file is. After knowing the structure you can then build your class. I have added a sample structure and how you can convert it into a Java class. Refer below.

Sample file structure

```
<Product>
    <Name>Widget</Name>
    <Description>
        This widget is the highest quality widget. 
    </Description>
    <Price>5.50</Price>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Glass</Name>
    <Description>
        This Glass is the highest quality glass. 
    </Description>
    <Price>6.50</Price>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Wood</Name>
    <Description>
        This wood is the highest quality wood. 
    </Description>
    <Price>70</Price>
    <Quantity>100</Quantity>
</Product>
```

From that you can see that there must be a `Product` class that will hold each product. And you can make your `Product` class like the below code.

(**Note: I have intentionally set all attributes as public since OP is a newbie**)
Product class

```
public class Product {
    public String name; // holder of the name of the product
    public String description; // holder of the description of the product
    public double price; // holder of the price of the product, the data type is double since it can contain decimal values
    public int quantity; // holder of the quantity of the product, the data type is int since a product can't usually have decimal values as quantity
}
```

You can also create a class that will hold your bill of materials.

Bill of materials class:

```
public class Bill {
     public List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>(); // this will hold all the product
     public double totalCost; // this will be the total of the bill of materials
}
```

Then you will just read the file on whatever way you want to read it. But I have made a pseudo code below.

Pseudo code in reading the file:

```
Declare a list that will hold all Products inside file
Declare a variable that will hold the total cost of the bill and set it to 0
iterate each Product in file {
    Declare a new Product variable that will contain a single Product of file
    Set the Product's name
    Set the Product's description
    Set the Product's price
    Set the Product's quantity
    Add this Product to the product list that was declare above
    Add the Product's price to the current total
}
Declare a new Bill variable that will contain the product list and the total cost
Set the Bill's productList to be the product list that was declare above
Set the Bill's totalCost to be the total cost of the bill that was declare above
```

Now that is a gist on how you can create a class structure from a bill of materials. 
Just get ideas from my answer and edit it according to your needs. I hope I have helped.

**EDIT: Regarding OP's comment**
You can do that this way:

```
<ProductA>
    <Name>HyBrid</Name>
    <Description>
        This HyBrid is the highest quality HyBrid. 
    </Description>
    <Price>50000</Price>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    <ProductBList>
        <Product>
            <Name>WidgetA</Name>
            <Description>
                This widgetA is the highest quality widgetA. 
            </Description>
            <Price>5.50</Price>
            <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>WidgetB</Name>
            <Description>
                This widgetB is the highest quality widgetB. 
            </Description>
            <Price>5.50</Price>
            <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        </Product>
    </ProductBList>
    <ProductCList>
        <Product>
            <Name>WidgetA</Name>
            <Description>
                This widgetA is the highest quality widgetA. 
            </Description>
            <Price>5.50</Price>
            <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>WidgetB</Name>
            <Description>
                This widgetB is the highest quality widgetB. 
            </Description>
            <Price>5.50</Price>
            <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>WidgetC</Name>
            <Description>
                This widgetC is the highest quality widgetC. 
            </Description>
            <Price>5.50</Price>
            <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        </Product>
    </ProductCList>
</ProductA>
```

Then you can have a class like this:

```
public class ProductA {
    public String name; // holder of the name of the product
    public String description; // holder of the description of the product
    public double price; // holder of the price of the product, the data type is double since it can contain decimal values
    public int quantity; // holder of the quantity of the product, the data type is int since a product can't usually have decimal values as quantity
    public List<Product> productBList = new ArrayList<>(); // holder for all productB
    public List<Product> productCList = new ArrayList<>(); // holder for all productC
}
```

Note that this approach won't limit the contents of productBList and productCList. Thus if you want to limit it, just use an array. Also you must check first if the file contains a valid xml before generating a class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. One further thing. How can I handle dependencies between objects. E.g. product A requires two products B and three products C in order to be built. I assume on the Java side, the proper way would be that every product has an array of pointer/references to the products it requires (e.g. product A has two references to products B and three references to product C). Could also be, that this approach is not the way to go. On the xml side however I don't really know how to do it right.

Comment: @AndreasZiegler I have edited my answer, just refer to it. And if it helped you solved your problem then please accept it as an answer and don't forget to upvote! :)